When in liwevire data listing when sweetalert2 alert is opened I lose rows count
In laravel 10 / filamentphp 3 app I added sweetalert2 support and show some alert error messages using this library,
but when I got 404 error on delete and show sweetalert2 error message - my list of data has 0 length, so I got message like "No data found".
In my component :
namespace App\Livewire\Admin;

...
use App\Models\StaffUser;
use Livewire\Component;
/*
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/staff-users
*/
class CrudStaffUsers extends Component
{
    // Listing component rows
    protected $staffUserDataRows = [];
    ...
    public function mount(string $defaultAction = '')
    {
        $this->retrieveDbData(1);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.crud-staff-users', [
            'staffUserDataRows' => $this->staffUserDataRows,
            'staffUserRowsCount' => $this->getStaffUserRowsCount()
        ])->layout('components.layouts.admin');
    }


    protected function retrieveDbData($from): void
    {
        $this->staffUserDataRows = StaffUser
            ::getByName($this->filters['name'], $this->filters['extended_search'])
            ->withCount('news')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(10);
    }

    public function updatedPage()
    {
        $this->retrieveDbData(2);
    }


    public function updated($property, $value)
    {
        $this->retrieveDbData(3);
    }


    public function paginationView()
    {
        return 'admin-tailwind';
    }



    protected function getStaffUserRowsCount()
    {
        return StaffUser
            ::getByName($this->filters['name'], $this->filters['extended_search'])
            ->count();
    }

    public function destroy(int $id)
    {
        try {
            $staffUser = StaffUser::getById($id+100)->firstOrFail();  // TRY INVALID ID
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            self::dispatchAlert(DispatchAlertTypeEnum::ERROR,'Deleting staff user: ' . $e->getMessage(), $this->pageTitle);
            return;
        }

        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $staffUser->delete();
            DB::commit();
        } catch (QueryException | \Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();
        }
    }
}

Method dispatchAlert calls event in resources/js/app.js:
window.addEventListener('clientAlert', (event) => {

    Swal.fire({
        icon: event.detail[0].type,
        title: event.detail[0].title,
        html: event.detail[0].message,
        showConfirmButton: true,
        timer: 4500
    });
})

and in blade template resources/views/livewire/admin/crud-staff-users.blade.php :
count($staffUserDataRows)::{{ print_r(count($staffUserDataRows), true)}};;<br>
$staffUserRowsCount::{{ print_r($staffUserRowsCount, true)}};;<br>


    @if(count($staffUserDataRows) == 0)
        <div class="m-2 p-2 warning_text">
            {!! AppIconFacade::get(IconEnum::Warning) !!}There are no staff users found !
        </div>
    @endif

    @if(count($staffUserDataRows) > 0)
        <div class="my-0 mx-2 p-0 overflow-x-auto">
            <table class="editor_listing_table mb-4">

So when sweetalert2 alert is opened  value count($staffUserDataRows) has 0 value. I suppose that as listibng lost focus I got this issue.
Can it be salved somehow? I would like some client library with with alert message...

When the deletion fails you have to load the data again which, being in a  protected variable, is not maintained (in fact you pass the variable to every render())

I tried to remake in declare :
public $staffUserDataRows = [];
but got error :
Property type not supported in Livewire for property: [{"current_page":1,"da...
Could you please detalize what have I to remake to make it working? Actually it works ok, until alert is shown...

I've added an answer

When a backend action is called using Livewire to manage an event, the render() method is executed.
Keep in mind also that on every call to the backend the class is reinstantiated.
So I suppose you have a Delete button which calls the destroy() method in the backend passing the record id.
When destroy() finishes, with or without an error, the variable $staffUserDataRows has the value set in the declaration, so it is an empty array.
A possible solution is to reload the variable content when you delete a row.
(Note that from what I can see from your code you could move the call to the retrieveDbData() method on the render() and execute it only there).
class MyComponent extends Component
{
    // Listing component rows
    protected $staffUserDataRows = [];

   .....

   public function destroy(int $id)
   {
       $errorMsg = '';
       $exception = NULL;

       try {
          $staffUser = StaffUser::getById($id+100)->firstOrFail();  // TRY INVALID ID

          DB::beginTransaction();
          $staffUser->delete();
          DB::commit();
       }
       catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {

          $errorMsg = 'Staff user not found';
          $exception = $e;
       }
       catch (QueryException | \Exception $e) {
          DB::rollBack();
          $errorMsg = 'Deleting staff user';
          $exception = $e;
       }
       finally {
           $this->retrieveDbData();
       }

       if ($exception) {

         self::dispatchAlert(DispatchAlertTypeEnum::ERROR,$errorMsg, $this->pageTitle);

         logger($exception->getMessage()); // this is a simple example 

       }
    }

   
    .....
    

    public function render()
    {
        // $this->retrieveDbData(); By enabling this line you can remove all other *$this->retrieveDbData()* in the class

        return view('livewire.sweet-alert03', [
            'staffUserDataRows' => $this->staffUserDataRows,
            'staffUserRowsCount' => $this->getStaffUserRowsCount()
        ])->layout('components.layouts.admin');
    }

    .....
}

